# HP e6500 "Printhead Missing" error - How to ignore and still use Scanner

Tags: printer

I have an HP Officejet e6500 All-in-One printer that has been giving me the "printhead missing" error, even though I have already replaced the printhead.

I cant seem to cancel out of the message or use any of the other features of the printer. I've called HP support about it and they've told me the only thing I can do is send it in for repair (which at this point i'd rather throw away the unit and buy a different brand).  I'm wondering if there is a way to cancel/ignore the error message and still use the scanner and copy features of the unit.